# How to determine whether a position is between to specific characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I explain my question using a few examples:

**Example1:**

```
var str = "this is a test
           and also this is a test
           and this";
```

The range: `[19 - 22] // "also"`

Now I need to check that `str` from start til position of `19` and from `22` til end of that string for being this character `$`. If there is, then return `true`, else return `false`. And in this case the output is:

```
false
```

---

**Example2:**

```
var str = "this $ is a test
           and also this is a test
           and this";
```

The range: `[21 - 24] // "also"`

Output:

```
false // there is $ before the range, but there isn't after it, so false
```

---

**Example3:**

```
var str = "this $ is a test
           and also this is a test
           and $this";
```

The range: `[21 - 24] // "also"`

Output:

```
true
```

---

**Example4:**

```
var str = "this $ is $ a test
           and also this is a test
           and $ this";
```

The range: `[23 - 26] // "also"`

Output:

```
false // there is two $ before the range and that means there isn't $ before  the range, so false
```

---

**Example5:**

```
var str = "this $ is $ $ a test
           and also this is a test
           and $ this";
```

The range: `[25 - 27] // "also"`

Output:

```
true
```

---

**Note:** I don't need to get that range using `indexOf()`, I already have those positions.

How can I do that?

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)  and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf). Notice also, that `str`s in your examples are invalid.

Comment: @Teemu Which `str` exactly? Do you mean I have you use `\n` instead of `Enter` button?

Comment: All of them. Not `\n`, but `\ ` or string concatenation.

Comment: You can extract strings before and after the positions and count the $ symbol in them. and the parity to calculate

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette Nice idea .. Counting the number of `$` before and after the range and determine their being *odd* or *even*  could be a good idea ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n= str.indexOf("also");
var pre=(str.substring(0,n).match(/\$/g) || []).length;
var post=(str.substring(n+3,str.length).match(/\$/g) || []).length;
if(pre %2 ===1 && post %2===1){
console.log(true)
} else {
console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: Actually my main question is *example4* that your solution ignored it

Comment: Ahh, I guess you updated by the time I was solving, or I might have overlooked

Comment: What is `3` in the `n+3` *(on third line)* ?

Comment: n+3 is the end index of word "also".